# Split caption of a figure into two equal lines

Tags: latex

I would like to split for example the phrase:

> Lower, upper and simulation throughput per user vs number of users

which appears in a caption of figure, into two lines in order for every line to have almost equal length. Something like the following:

> Lower, upper and simulation
>   throughput per user vs number of users

How can I do that? I would appreciate any help!

Comment: (La)TeX-related questions are better asked at [tex.se]. Your question has been flagged so that it gets migrated there.

Comment: Is this just for one caption? Is the alignment you propose (`\raggedright`) what you're after? What about the caption label `Figure x: `? Do you want that as part of the re-alignment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could wrap the contents in a `varwidth` environment (from the similarly-named [`varwidth` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/varwidth)) of large-enough width. `varwidth` will shrink it to fit that natural content:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\usepackage{varwidth}% http://ctan.org/pkg/varwidth
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=.5]{example-image-a}% Image
  \caption[Lower, upper and simulation throughput per user \textit{vs.}\ number of users]
    {\begin{varwidth}[t]{\linewidth}Lower, upper and simulation \\ throughput per user \textit{vs.}\ number of users\end{varwidth}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The reason for specifying the caption twice (once in the option argument `[]` and once as part of the mandatory argument `{}`) is because sending a box-constrained piece of text to the ToC doesn't look great. So, this separates the formatting between the two document components. Depending on the document class you're using, it is also possible to make this part of the regular label-setting requirements.

The [`caption` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) also provides `format=hang` with `justification=raggedright` that seems to duplicate your requirement. However, you'll have to play with the margins to adequately obtain the output you're after.

Comment: It was easier tha I expected. I used the \captionsetup{justification=centering} and divided it like \caption{Lower, Upper and simulation throughput \\ per user vs number of users for simple network}